# JQuery unrecognized expression. Linking in Foundation

Tags: jquery, html, zurb-foundation

I have this links:

```
<nav>
    <div class="myClass" id="myId">
        <ul class="right">
            <li><a href="#foo">Link 1</a></li> <
            <li><a href="http://subdomain.mywebsite.com">Subdomain</a></li>
            <li><a href="/foo">Foo</a></li>
       </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

The first one works great but at the other two I get this error in the browser console:

```
Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: /foo               jquery.js:24:10790
```

The interesting thing is that I have other links made like this and they work perfect:

```
<nav class="myClass">
    <ul class="myOtherClass">
        <li><a href="http://something.com">Domain</a></li>
        <li><a href="/foo" target="_blank">Foo</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://mySubdomain.myDomain.com">Subdomain</a></li>
   </ul>
</nav>
```

I'm not sure why this happens. I use Zurb Foundation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see,
you have last two href content wrong as below:

```
<li><a href="/fun">Fun Ranch</a></li>
<li><a href="#/test">Test</a></li>

<li><a href="#fun">Fun Ranch</a></li> makes the page scroll to that id 'fun' but '/fun' is another path in web. Please check.
```

Comment: It should link to the path "/fun" but there's this error. The page scroll links work perfectly.

Comment: For solving the issue you can use `onclick` on tag. 
`<a href="" onclick="window.location.href='https://<full-url>/fun'"></>`

Comment: Thanks a lot. Does this work in every major browser?